# How to add 'Bourne Again Shell (bash)' to ignored_packages?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to add `Bourne Again Shell (bash)` to my list of `ignored_packages`.

I've tried `Bourne Again Shell (bash)`, `Bourne Again Shell`, `bash`, `Bash`, and several other permutations. None of them work. What should be the correct value for this?

Additionally, if there's a way to list all the package names that `ignored_packages` recognizes, that would be super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of packages is taken from:

- The names of all of the folders in the `Packages` folder, which you can get to by using `Preferences: Browse Packages` from the command palette or the main menu
- The names of all of the `sublime-package` files contained in the `Installed Packages` folder, which you can get to by going up one directory level from the `Packages` folder above
- The names of all of the `sublime-package` files contained in the `Packages` folder inside of the directory that Sublime is installed in.

The [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit) package (disclaimer: I am the author) includes a command named `OverrideAudit: Package Report` that lists the names of all packages as well.

All that said, if you're using Package Control, you can choose the `Package Control: Disable Package` command from the command palette and interactively select the package you want to disable; that command adds the package you select to the setting for you.

That's generally the preferred way to go if you're not sure, as the command hides the names of packages that it's not safe to ignore (such as the `Default` package and your `User` package).

It sounds like you may want to disable the bash syntax that ships with Sublime; if that's the case, it's stored in the `ShellScript` package.